# Jobs developer story shows incorrect company logo

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, status-planned, developer-story

How do I tell jobs to not use an old logo for the company I am at?

It keeps trying to tell me to use this:

[image]

But our company name and logo changed about a year ago.  I also manage job postings on SO careers / jobs.  And I have indicated through the company page that our logo and name has changed as shown:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/thyssenkrupp-system-engineering

Here's the uploaded image:

[image]

But whatever I do in my developer story won't allow me to change this image, as shown:

[image]

Who manages the images and or company names?

Comment: -1 for lack of free-hand circles.

Comment: The problem seems to be that company data (or at least the logos) comes from CrunchBase. Furthermore, it's loaded from http://public.crunchbase.com/ over http:// which causes a mixed-content warning when using SO via https.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many companies in the developer story dropdown list, like thyssenkrupp System Engineering, were seeded from Crunchbase before we launched. The data we obtained from Crunchbase were company names, websites, and logos.

Currently the companies in the developer story are not connected to the companies in stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies. Linking the developer story companies to jobs company pages is something we plan to do in the future. For now, if you would like to change the name, website, or logo of your developer story item, you can press the x button in the Company input field to unlock the fields.

I went ahead and updated the logo for this company.