# Places of employment not recognised in developer story

Tags: discussion, developer-story

I've only ever worked two places before, and decided to add them to my Developer Story. One of them seemed 'officially recognised', in the sense that Stack Overflow was able to get the website and logo for them automatically, but the other was not. While I do realise that I can add the website and logo myself, I am curious as to how some companies are recognised automatically and some are not.

I can't find anything official about the process, but was able to find [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339128/jobs-developer-story-shows-incorrect-company-logo), in which the answerer mentions the Crunchbase database that *was* being used. How are companies put into the database currently? How can they get added in future? Is there anything the community can do to help with the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that we've used Crunchbase to "seed" our list of companies. This list is updated each time someone adds an unknown company with a logo and URL. The new company then becomes available for other users to reuse.

In your example the company wasn't already in our list and without a logo and URL it hasn't been made available for other users.

The community can't currently help populate this list explicitly. But by adding logos and URLs to your positions means that other users who have worked at the same place will have an easier time adding their work history.

Comment: So simply put, if I were to add a logo and URL, anyone else wanting to add that company to their story would have the logo and URL that I provided suggested to them?

Comment: @ISOmetric spot on!

Comment: Okay, that's good to know - thanks!